# A question on sampling distributions

Tags: sampling, mean

I once read the following interesting  distribution related question:

> An insurance company identified the 10 safest and 10 least-safe cities
>   from 200  cities in the US based on the mean number of years drivers
>   went between automobile  accidents. It turns out that the cities on
>   both lists were all smaller than the 10  largest cities in the list of
>   200 cities.
>
> How do we use the sampling distribution model of the mean to explain
>   this fact?

Comment: Hint: Consider the impact of sample size on the standard error of the mean

Comment: For this question, should I assume that the city with larger size should have a larger sample than the city with smaller size?

Comment: Could I understand this way? For larger cities, the sample mean is very close to the real mean. For small cities, the sample mean can be skewed to either smaller side or the larger side due to the smaller sample size, and they are easily to be chosen to be safe or less-safe.

Comment: @user3269. You answered your own question perfectly in the comment above. Turn that into a proper answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: A famous example of this concerns mapping cancer mortality rates by administrative region within a country (such as counties within the US): both the highest and lowest rates tend to occur within the least-populous units. See, *inter alia*, Gelman and Price, [All maps of parameter estimates are misleading](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/allmaps.pdf). Note that this is not a *sample* size effect; it's a *population* size effect.

Comment: @Whuber, how to understand the difference between sample size effect and population size effect. It seems that there is a strong correlation between sample size and population size. The large population can have large sample size.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hint of Henry and Harvey. I think this question can be answered as follows:

We can assume that large cities tend to have large sample sets. With larger sample set, the sample mean tends to approximate the population mean. On the other side, the sample mean for the smaller cities tends to either skewed to the smaller side(less-safe) or the larger side(safe side). This make them more easily to be identified as safe or less safe cities.

Comment: There's at least one article by Thomas Kane and Douglas Staiger, c. 2000, that's relevant to this topic.

Comment: I believe this answer confuses *population* with *sample.*  The question concerns data about *entire populations* (the cities), not samples from those cities.  The point of the question is that when there is no association between safety and location, each city can be viewed *as if* it were a random sample from the entire population of drivers in all 200 cities.  The variance of the mean will be higher in smaller cities.